# Proof relatively prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p,q,r$ be three distinct prime numbers and $m = p\times q\times r$. 
How many of the numbers {$1,2,...,m$} are relatively prime to $m$?

**My attempt**:

1. $m=2 \times 3 \times 5=30$,
2. $m=2\times 3 \times 7=42$,
3. $m=3\times 5\times 7=105$,

and I see the pattern that relatively prime numbers to $m$ are prime numbers(and their powers) except {$p,q,r$}. Prime factorization of $m$ is $p\times q\times r$ and I can maybe argue that $m$ cannot be divided by any other prime number.

But how do I prove this more formally ? I can't see any formal way to do it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler’s totient function(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)?

Comment: I didn't realize it was Euler's totien function, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clearly see it from Euler's totient function.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is given by Euler's totient function, which can be computed explicitly using Euler's product formula (see: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function))

If this machinery seems too complex, since the number you're dealing with only has three primes in its prime factorization, you could consider a "Brute Force" approach:

Let $A^{\ell}_{m} :={\{x : x=c\cdot \ell,\ c\in \mathbb{N}, x\leq m}\}$

Note that the sets $A^{p}_{m},\ A^{q}_{m},\ A^{r}_{m},\ A^{pq}_{m},\ A^{pr}_{m},\ A^{qr}_{m}$ contain all natural numbers that are NOT relatively prime to $m$.

So how many of the numbers ${\{1,2,...,m}\}$ are relatively prime to $m$?
$$m-\vert A^{p}_{m} \cup A^{q}_{m}\cup A^{r}_{m}\cup A^{pq}_{m}\cup A^{pr}_{m}\cup A^{qr}_{m} \vert $$

Note that there is some overlap between these sets, but the size of the union can easily be determined using inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple counting problem disguised as number theory. Among the numbers $1,2,\ldots,m$, it is easy to count the number of multiples of $p$, those which are multiples of $q$, and those which are multiples of $r$. Now we need to exclude numbers which we counted twice, and add back those we excluded too many times. This idea is known as the [Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and is a well-known method of counting. This can be applied to your case to find the answer, and can also be generalised to an arbitrary number of primes.